# Rails ActiveSupport not loaded when deploying via Capistrano

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, capistrano, ubuntu-10.04, linode

I'm following this guide for deploying a rails app via capistrano: https://github.com/capistrano/capistrano/wiki/2.x-From-The-Beginning

I'm using linode as my VPS. I've done all the initial setup and `cap deploy:setup/update/deploy` all work. When I go to execute this command in my rails directory: `$ rake RAILS_ENV=production db:schema:load`. I get `undefined method 'minutes' for 90:Fixnum`. It seems that activesupport is somehow not installed, yet when I type `rails --version`, I get `Rails 3.2.11`. Any insight would be extremely helpful!

Here's my `deploy.rb` file:

```
require 'bundler/capistrano'
require "capistrano-rbenv"
set :rbenv_ruby_version, "1.9.3-p392"

set :application, "uganda-coords"

# Deploy from your local Git repo by cloning and uploading a tarball
set :scm, :git
set :repository,  "git@github.com:benrudolph/myapp.git"
set :deploy_via, :copy
set :scm_passphrase, "mypassword"
set :branch, "master"
set :deploy_via, :remote_cache
set :rails_env,     "production"


set :user, :root
set :deploy_to, "/var/www/#{application}"
set :use_sudo, false
set :ssh_options, { :forward_agent => true }

role :web, "176.58.105.165"                          # Your HTTP server, Apache/etc
role :app, "176.58.105.165"                          # This may be the same as your `Web` server
role :db,  "176.58.105.165", :primary => true # This is where Rails migrations will run

namespace :deploy do
  task :start do ; end
  task :stop do ; end
  task :restart, :roles => :app, :except => { :no_release => true } do
   run "#{try_sudo} touch #{File.join(current_path,'tmp','restart.txt')}"
  end
end
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out this had to do with using `90.minutes` in my `application.rb` file. I still don't know why this works on dev and not production.